# How NHibernate cache native queries?

Tags: nhibernate, native-sql

I have native sql query using in global NHibernate common session like

```
string sql = @"update Accounts 
 set vchBranch = :branch,                               
 bitIsActive = :isActive, 
 bitIsVisible = :isVisible              
 where bintId = :id";

ISQLQuery sqlQuery = HibernateUtil.GetCurrentSession().CreateSQLQuery(sql);

sqlQuery.SetBoolean("isActive", account.IsActive);
sqlQuery.SetBoolean("isVisible", account.IsVisible);
sqlQuery.SetInt64("id", account.Id);
sqlQuery.ExecuteUpdate();
```

Is NHibernate cache result of this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer. It caching result object in Nhibernate session.
In mapping XML-file I found references to model objects.